# Is it possible to add additional custom paths to Git to be searched for scripts and commands via gitconfig or similar?

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up my portable Git to search for additional scripts in a specific folder.

Consider this example directory tree structure

```
-- my-portable-git
│
├───git-scripts
│       git-myscript
│       ⋮       # some more scripts
└───portable-git
        ⋮       # rest of files for portable git
```

Since I can't edit my `PATH` env variable for `$reasons`, is it possible to add via `.gitconfig`, or by other means, additional paths for `git` to use when calling scripts/commands/etc?

Referring to example above: is it possible to say to `git` "*oi git*, look also into folder `../git-scripts/` for more commands please!" without editing the `PATH` env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for a quick batch script, and yes what Torek suggested is indeed more sensed with this solution.
Works well and more paths can be added if needed.

```
:: Git wrapper to ensure this folder is included in the PATH
:: gitw.cmd

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

set "_GITW_DIR=%~dp0"

set "PATH=%_GITW_DIR%;%PATH%"

:: just an additional echo for the passed git command, can be removed
echo CMD: %*

"path\to\your\binary\git.exe" %*

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set the `GIT_EXEC_PATH` environment variable.

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Comment: Interesting but unfortunately I don't have an active shell where I can change env vars, maybe I can hack a git *wrapper* that will set the env first....

Comment: @Gruber: of course, if you can insert a wrapper, you can insert one that sets $PATH too/instead :-)